# Appendix numbering with appendix package

Tags: numbering, appendices, appendix

I'm trying to setup my appendix using `appendix` package. Following my guidelines I should number appendices as "Appendix 1", "Appendix 2", etc (it's Cyrillic, but it's not the question). 
By default the numbering looks like "Appendix A", "Appendix B".
So I'm using

```
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

in preamble, as documentation suggests. It doesn't work.
When I try to setup another way

```
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{5cm}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix~\arabic{section}}
```

it messes up my ToC.

The appendix itself is set up like that:

```
\begin{appendices}
    \section{Spectra}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \end{figure}
\end{appendices}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, final]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\PolyglossiaSetup{russian}{indentfirst=true}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}
% \usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{section}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
    \section{Spectra}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is what I get]

Looks like the appendices numbering is overridden by something.

Comment: The question should contain a *complete* but minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found the solution: if

```
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
    \makeatother
```

is inserted after `\begin{appendices}` everything works as expected.
It comes from the way the numeration is set up in `appendix` package.